# How a 4 bit CPU Works on infinite data and recall that data from memory?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, processor, cpu-cache

Consider, a processor with only 4 transistors. It can represent only one nibble at a time. we need to work on data consist of 32bits (correction: i removed "infinite bytes" from here). how it can save? so that we input second nibble and so on.... and how we recall saved data? and also explain when we represent binary to octal or decimal, which cpu unit do this representations?

Comment: Be a little bit more descriptive in your question and what exactly you wanna ask. This. question is too subjective

Comment: i need to know the internal working of cpu.

Comment: You can't build a CPU out of only 4 transistors.  That's enough for about one gate, or maybe 1 latch (to hold one true/false state).  When people say "4-bit CPU", they mean its registers or ALU are 4 bits wide; it would still take thousands of transistors to build.

Comment: octal and decimal are text serialization formats for numbers.  There are multiple ways to represent or print a binary number, but inside the CPU it's just binary.

Comment: just assume that we have only 4 bits in processor... and we need to represent 32bits of data... then how computation works with which parts of cpu are necessary .  how data store in memory and how to input new data...etc .. and also mention which cpu part resposible for data representation from binary to decimal or decimal to binary

Comment: "4-bit CPU" doesn't mean only 4 bits of internal storage total.  You're still going to have multiple internal 4-bit-wide latches to move data around between parts of the CPU.  You tagged this "cpu-cache" so if you want to have a cache at all, you automatically need storage for data and tags.  With 32-bit addresses the tags are going to be something like 20 bits each.  (e.g. assuming 6 bits for byte-within-line and another 6 bits to index a set.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is literally infinite like a true Turing machine, you need to be able to use variable-sized addresses.  Or some way to move along a tape in a potentially-infinite number of finite steps.  i.e. use storage that you can do relative seeks on, instead of every storage location even having an address.

No existing RAM-based CPUs do that; they always pick a fixed finite address width.  e.g. 8-bit, allowing you to address up to 256 different memory locations.

You can't pick fixed width = infinite because then you'd need an infinite number of transistors to build your CPU.  (Instead of "just" an infinite amount of time to process infinite-sized problems, and finite time for finite-sized problems.)

Comment: sorry i wrote infinite mistakenly... assume that we have to represent finite data consist of 32bit. how computation works... how data store in memory and how to input new data...etc .. and also mention which cpu part resposible for data representation from binary to decimal or decimal to binary

Answer (score 0):

Memory management is the functionality of an operating system which handles or manages primary memory(or RAM) and moves processes back and forth between main memory and disk during execution. Memory management keeps track of each and every memory location, regardless of either it is allocated to some process or it is free. It checks how much memory is to be allocated to processes. It decides which process will get memory at what time. It tracks whenever some memory gets freed or unallocated and correspondingly it updates the status. I hope this links helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_(operating_systems) and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_memory_management.htm